# Why the error in the c++ code while use cout/cin?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
 char* name;
 std::cout<<"Ingresa tu nombre: \t";
 std::cin>>name;
 std::cout<<"Tu nombre es: \t"<<name;
 return 0;
}
```

When the variable name is of type `int`, it works fine, but when the variable is of type `char`, to store the whole name, when entering it the program says that it has stopped working, and does not even manage to show the name, in the last `cout`.

[image]

Comment: What string buffer does `name` point to?

Comment: `name` is not of type `char`. It is of type `char *`, i.e. pointer to char. Pointers don't store data, they point to data. Your `name` doesn't point anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You're reading input into an uninitialized character buffer pointer, basically dumping input into some random chunk of memory, so this is undefined behaviour and it will crash.

You need to initialize that buffer prior to use, or, the C++ solution here is to use a string:

```
std::string name;
```

That handles memory management for you automatically and doesn't suffer from the buffer overflow problems intrinsic to C.

Comment: It's not an uninitialised character buffer; it's a _non-existent_ character buffer. The pointer that would have pointed to said buffer is uninitialised.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True, it's both uninitialized and unallocated.

Comment: There is no "it" :)

Answer (score 2):

`char* name;` is a pointer. It needs to point to some memory. Currently it is uninitialized so it could point anywhere or to anything. This means when you do this; `std::cin>>name;` it will write randomly into your programs space as if it were writing into a buffer. This is undefined behaviour and can result in anything, including working correctly or crashing as it does in your case. In c++, you can use a `std::string` to read into:

```
std::string name;
std::cin>>name;
```

Comment: Given that, why does C++ allow `>>` to target `char*` at all, vs give a compiler error?

Comment: @HostileFork what if the had initialised the buffer correctly? With `char arr[1000]` or similar?

Comment: What proves any amount of fixed storage is enough space?  Where's the contract?

Comment: @HostileFork there isn't one. This is c++, not a high level programing language. It's use at your own perril. Just like this compiles: `int arr[2]; arr[3] = 1`. Just because it compiles doesn't mean it is correct.

Comment: ...just trying to point out that your answer of "use a std::string" skips out on what I believe is core in the question (which Lightness thinks is too dumb for anyone to ask), but if you don't address *why the code given compiles in the first place* I think it misses out on why someone who's read some C and some C++ would end up with the problem.

Comment: @HostileFork The answer is not just "use a `std::string`". It gives a detailed explanation of why the OP code doesnt work. The `std::string` is likely a very sound suggestion for a fix. The question `Why the error in the c++ code while use cout/cin?` is very much answered in the paragraph of text.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: actually, there *is* a contract: when using the input operator with a `char*` the user of this operator is supposed to set up the stream’s width with the amount of available space or to guarantee that there is enough space (the latter can be done by knowing how many characters can be read at most because the input is known, e.g., because the stream is an `std::istringstream`).

Comment: @DietmarKühl HostileFork was talking about a contract that covers for any amount of space and why not disallow char* because it cant meet such a contract. Sure, the concept is that the user use this correctly, but that can easily be broken.